# Update path of uploaded image into db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is this the correct way to edit an inserted rows, fields with the name of an image path.

```
$query = "UPDATE products SET image = $_FILES["file"]["name"] WHERE name = $name";
```

I am more concerned with the sql syntax then the php for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around strings, and you should make sure to sanitize the inputs (or better yet, use parameterization - see [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)).

```
$filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

$query = "UPDATE products SET image = '{$filename}' WHERE name = '{$name}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes, and probably mysql_real_escape_string

```
$query = "UPDATE products SET image = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["file"]["name"])."' WHERE name = '$name'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice quotes

```
$query = "UPDATE products SET image ='". mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["file"]["name"]) ."' WHERE name ='". $name."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = sprintf('UPDATE products SET image="%s" WHERE name="%s"',
    mysql_escape_string($_FILES["file"]["name"]),
    mysql_escape_string($name)
);
```